# XML serialize .net decimal to always contain two significant digits

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am attempting to call a SOAP service, believed to be written in Java, which takes a decimal as a value. The contract was generated by .NET 4.6.1 System.ServiceModel. Do to some oddities with the service being called, it is necessary to send 10.00 vs 10.0. I am able to send "10.00" as a string, but don't want to modify the contract in case it needs to be regenerated. The contract is a public partial class, and I have implemented a partial inheriting from IXmlSerializable where the decimal is converted as a string with two decimal places. However, when running tests through this code the following error is generated:

> ...
>   "exceptionMessage\\":\\"Only XmlRoot attribute may be specified for
>   the type MyPainfulClass. Please use XmlSchemaProviderAttribute to
>   specify schema
>   type.\\",\\"exceptionType\\":\\"System.InvalidOperationException\\",\\"stackTrace\\":\\"
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter)\\"}}}}}}}}}}}}}}\"}"

This seems to be the same solution that John recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678258/how-to-override-c-sharp-datetime-serialization-with-class-auto-generated-from-ws).

I did decorate the extended class with XmlSchemaProviderAttribute, but am unsure if I'm referencing the correct .xsd as the service fairly tangled. Is there a better way to deffer to the generated class for the schema? My end goal is to simply override the XML serialization to string.

```
namespace PainfulService.Contract
{
    using System;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Schema;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    [XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("http://painfulservice.com/headache/v1_01.xsd")]
    public partial class MyPainfulClass : IXmlSerializable
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
        public string PriceAsString
        {
            get
            {
                return this.priceField.ToString("0.00");
            }
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            Price = decimal.Parse(element.XPathSelectElement("PriceAsString").Value);
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("Price", PriceAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only tangentially related: I'd suggest formatting and parsing your `decimal` using  [`NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo.aspx) since this is what [`XmlConvert.ToDecimal()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlConvert.cs,9937960b31f70d8c,references) does.